# How to specify the domain for a man page

Tags: c, openssl, rsa, manpage

I am trying to get man page for `OpenSSL` rsa. However when I type in `man rsa` I get the bash command `rsa` instead. How do I specify in the `man` command such that the `OpenSSL RSA` page will be displayed?

Comment: Try `man man` perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to see the man page of RSA_new, RSA_free function.

Please try

```
 man 3 rsa
```

You will get the man page of RSA functions and structure description.

Comment: Thanks I see it, 3 means Library calls.